# Non english characters in database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, non-english

I have to save non-english (special character) in MySql using Java code , When i am trying to do so data is getting saved as ??????

```
String dataStr  = "κωνσταντίνα";
            System.out.println("Before " + dataStr);
             String dataStr1 = new String(dataStr.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"); 
             System.out.println("after "+dataStr1);
            String st = URLDecoder.decode("κωνσταντίνα", "UTF-8");
            cd.setTransactionDescription(dataStr1);
```

Comment: Why are you converting it to ISO-8859-1 and then interpreting the results as UTF-8? That's pretty much bound to go wrong (at least for any non-ASCII data). Why are you doing *any* of this, rather than just setting the transaction description to `dataStr`?

Comment: The IDE must use UTF-8 too for editor and javac compiler. And then `System.out.println` is not fit for UTF-8, It outputs to the console with probably the operating system encoding. That converts java String (Unicode) to the Windows encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You really should try making everything UTF-8 from point to point.

Use appropriate unicode aware collation for database and table, I always give per table even if db default was already given. This answer has a lot of mysql+java and also servlet issues but they should answer most issues we need to know when developing unicode aware java applications.

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE tMyTable (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  code VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Use jdbc connection string to have unicode translation.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  maxActive="10" maxIdle="2" maxWait="10000"
  username="myuid" password="mypwd"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
  validationQuery="SELECT 1"
/>
```

Force Tomcat to use content-type charset for both GET and POST parameter strings, so apply useBodyEncodingForURI attribute for http and https connectors (tomcat/conf/server.xml file).

```
<Connector port="8080"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           debug="0" connectionTimeout="20000"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
/>
```

At the start of each servlet page make sure Tomcat parsers request parameters as utf-8. You need to call setCharacterEncoding before reading parameters or it's too late. Most web browsers don't send content-type charset attribute so servlet engines may guess it wrong.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws ServletException { doPost(req, res); }

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws ServletException {
   if (req.getCharacterEncoding() == null)
      req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

   String value = request.getParameter("fieldName");
   ...
}
```

Be careful with .jsp page do not insert an empty leading whitechars or it may be too late calling setCharacterEncoding, see how I put tag markers at the end of each row to avoid any whitechars, also how html elements start from the first line. Jsp tag `contentType` goes to http response and `pageEncoding` means how file is stored in a disk. If you have ISO-8859-15 text editor only and do not hardcode i18n letters in a jsp page you may choose proper iso* pageEncoding.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><%@ 
    taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"  %><%@ 
    page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
    import="java.util.*,
             java.io.*
    "
%><%
   if (req.getCharacterEncoding() == null)
      request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   String param1 = request.getParameter("fieldName");
%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="some,fine,keywords" />
</head>
<body>
your html content goes here.... <%= param1 %>
</body>
</html>
```

Creating xml document in jsp page you need to write xml header without leading whitechars or newlines. See how scriptlet endtag and xml header is in a same line. This is what embedded jsp code must always take into consideration, innocent leading whitechar may ruin well formatted replys.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><%@ 
    page contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
    import="java.util.*, 
             java.io.*
    "
%><%
  // MyBean has getId() and getName() getters
  List<MyBean> items = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
  items.add( new MyBean(1, "first") );
  items.add( new MyBean(2, "second") );
  items.add( new MyBean(3, "third") );

  pageContext.setAttribute("items", items);
%><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mydoc>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}">
  <item>
    <id>${item.id}</id>
    <name>${item.name}</name>
  </item>
</c:forEach>
</mydoc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reasone because this happens is wrong encoding in JavaClass. 
Also i advice you to check your MySQL database encoding.

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

Check this db-serverSide params

```
character_set_results 
character_set_connection
character_set_client
```