# java utf-8 encoding character doesn't show correct in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a jsp page that have some text filed to submitted some information.
my problem is with utf-8 characters.
at top of this page i imported pageEncoding as utf-8 and charset as utf-8.
when i post some value in utf-8 encoding, characters do not show  or save in database correct.
some thing amazing is with same import at another page every thing is work fine.
I read a lot of questions and article and almost i do every thing but it doesn't fix.
another magically happen the character is basically utf-8 but doesn't show correct at unicode. I really appreciate that some guys help me.
and here is my page encoding import :

Comment: can't see your code i.e encoding import page

Comment: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

Comment: See this for more detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33671273/185565

Comment: You should add code of the two pages to your question.

Comment: Make sure your database and table as UTF 8 collation. By default it is latin